# How to use angular-split in Angular 11 version

Tags: angular

I am using Angular 11 for my current project. I got a requirement which was built-in with angular-split and angular-split is released in 13 version, So I am finding for the alternative. Can anyone help me how can we achieve angular-split functionalities in Angular 11.

Thanks

Comment: There are many versions of angular-split. I think you find some thats working with angular 11 https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-split

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.